# How can I save parameter (passed by C function call) to global variable in assembler x86-64?

Tags: assembly, x86-64

in my test.c file:

```
size_t var = 1000;
foo(var);
```

in test.h:

```
int *foo(size_t var);
```

in test.asm:

```
global foo
section .bss
    N: resd 0
; ...
foo:
    ; how can I get to "var" here and how can I write it to "N"?
```

I tried writing something like:

```
push    rbp
mov     rbp, rsp
mov     rax, [rbp+8]
mov     [N], rax
pop     rbp
ret
```

or

```
mov [N], rdi
ret
```

...but in both cases I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error, and, in fact, I'm not even sure what's happening here. I'm using nasm and gcc. Here is a short version that I can't get to work: http://pastebin.com/WELNeRXy

Comment: What assembler do you use? Is this nasm?

Comment: yes. I'm using nasm and gcc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that on amd64, UNIX-like operating systems (such as Linux) typically follow the *sysV-ABI.* Among other things, the ABI specifies how parameters are passed to functions. On amd64 with the SysV-ABI, the first few parameters are passed in the registers `rdi`, `rsi`, and `rdx`. So when `foo` is called, the caller will have placed `var` in `rdi`. So the correct code would be something like this:

```
foo:
    mov [N],rdi
    ret
```

To facilitate position independent code, you might also want to use an *instruction pointer relative* addressing mode. This is done using the `rel` keyword:

```
foo:
    mov [rel N],rdi
    ret
```

Further note that you actually need to allocate eight bytes of storage for `N`. Change the definition of `N` to something like this:

```
    section .bss
N:  resq 1
```

This reserves one quadword (eight byte) for `N`.

You can find further information about the SysV ABI elsewhere.

Comment: I tried doing it like this, but it didn't work for me. Here's a short version that I can't get to work http://pastebin.com/WELNeRXy

Comment: @Jecke Please read the note I wrote about actually reserving space for `N`. `resd` reserves as many doublewords as you specify. If you write `resd 0`, zero doublewords are reserved, which isn't enough to store one quadword (two doublewords).

Comment: @Jecke And lastly, note that the section names do not end in a colon!